# Validate user input in using Global variables

Tags: python, variables, global

I would like a user to input numbers from 1 to 4 and check they are in this range. I have modified some code which I found on Stack Overflow . Is this a good way to validate? Could I have accessed  the variables `guessX` and `guessY` without declaring them as global variables?

I get the error:

> SyntaxWarning: name 'guessY' is assigned to before global declaration

My code:

```
def validNum(guessX,guessY):
    if guessX < 1 or guessY < 1 or guessX > 4 or guessY > 4:
        print ("Guess is not in range and should be between \
               1 and 4. Try again.")
        return 0

    else:
        return 1

def getInput():
    while 1:
        guessX = int(input("Enter your guess for the X coordinate: "))
        guessY = int(input("Enter your guess for the Y coordinate: "))

        if validNum(guessX, guessY):
            break
    print ("good: %s is a valid coordinate for X." % guessX)
    print ("good: %s is a valid coordinate for Y." % guessY)
    # Is it a bad idea to declare guessX and GuessY as global?
    global guessX
    global guessY
```

Answer (score 1):

That is not technically an error.  Instead, it is a warning from Python that your code may be incorrect.

Specifically, it is complaining that you used the names `guessX` and `guessY` before you declared them as being global with `global`.  Code that does this is not regarding the global status of the names as it should and is usually invalid or logically flawed.

To fix the problem, simply move your global declarations to the top of the function:

```
def getInput():
    global guessX
    global guessY
    ...
```

Or, more simply:

```
def getInput():
    global guessX, guessY
    ...
```

In fact, `global` declarations should always be at the top of functions so that they are easily visible.

Note however that it is a best practice to avoid global variables in Python.  Most of the time, the presence of `global x` in a program means that the design needs reworking.

Comment: Thank you. Super swift reply!  Works fine and Python not complaining anymore. Not so sure on how to rework. Maybe I need to look at more examples on validating inputs

Comment: @StiofanONia - avoiding globals is nothing to do with validating inputs. it has everything to do with good designs. The classic way to avoid globals is to use classes.

Comment: I guess that I need to look at some tutorials using classes. Hadn't quite got that far yet. Thanks for the tip

Comment: @StiofanONia - It actually looks like you do not need the `global` declarations at all since you are passing the `guessX` and `guessY` values to `validNum` (as you should).  Instead of altering globals, you should stick with passing values to functions and then (re)assigning names to their return values.

Comment: Thanks I did as you had suggested re assigning names to the return values and was able to avoid using global variables.

Comment: Happy to have helped!  Please do not forget to accept my answer though by clicking the check.  Doing so lets people know that this problem is solved.